# Will I lose my saves if I uninstall Mass Effect 2?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-2

I know there are ways I can copy these files on my own and avoid this question completely, but I'm curious for the less tech saavy...  If I were to uninstall Mass Effect 2 would I lose my saves?  Is there a dialog box on uninstallation that gives me an option?  Does it not mention it at all and just leaves it in the directory where they were originally while deleting other game content?  Does Steam save any of this info in case of a total fail on my SSD's part.  I'm not taking any chances on this considering the hours I put in on 2...

note: my question pertains specifically to the PC title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you begin to uninstall the game via it's uninstaller, you will see the following:

[image]

**Make sure you tick the checkbox for Keep Save Games if you want to keep your saved games!**

Note: I do not have the Steam version, so I am unable to test what happens if you just right-click on the game in Steam and select "Delete Local Content". To be on the safe side, run the uninstaller as I did, through **Control Panel->Programs->Uninstall a program**

[image]

Comment: You can also make a physical backup of your saves from documents>bioware>mass effect 2>save